# Remove a folder from the JDeveloper find in files search option

Tags: file, search, jdeveloper

We're using JDeveloper at work and we are using a library that contains 15000 files inside its parent folder (ExtJS). Every time we want to look for something via the search->find in files it goes on and searches through the whole project including that library. How can I remove that folder from the search items?

Answer (score 0):

Check the working-set feature to see if it helps - https://blogs.oracle.com/jheadstart/entry/jdeveloper_11g_working_sets_ho

Comment: When I tried to remove the extjs folder from the working set it all seemed to go well but then when I tried to search through the files it would still search the extjs folder... I followed the guide to the point but still didn't work.